# For responsive design, how can I include a different header.php file for mobile users?

Tags: javascript, php, responsive

I want to change my header.php file for mobile devices.  I've tried this javascript solution but it doesn't write the php file.  How can I fix this?

```
<script language=javascript>
if (screen.width >= 720 ) 
     $('#header').load('header.php');
else (
     $('#header').load('header-mobile.php');
)
</script>
<div id="header"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap is a great option for working with responsive websites, have you considered using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to import different files? You could use media queries with css and add a class to each type of header like this:

```
<div class="mobile-header">
</div>
<div class="header">
</div>
```

And in CSS you just hide it/show it with media queries:

```
.header-mobile { 
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .header {
        display: none;
    }
    .header-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This means that your .header-mobile div is going to be hidden, unless your window size is 600px or less, in that case, your .header is going to be hidden.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This looks more like what I think of as responsive design.

Comment: It was because I'm using an image map for the linking, I thought I needed separate files - but this works perfectly.  Thanks!